# coding android Accelerometer in class

Tags: java, android, accelerometer

I'm writing an app that show accelerometer readings, I was able yesterday to write all the accelerometer code in the main activity and it works fine on emulator and my device.

But today I was trying to make a function that contains all the accelerometer code and return the three integers X,Y,Z in integer array, so I make a code that I think it`s right but every time I run the project the emulator gives an error "Unfortunately app-name has stopped" .

So I wish any help , please .

LogCat:

```
04-27 20:39:27.098: W/dalvikvm(812): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
04-27 20:39:27.118: E/AndroidRuntime(812): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 20:39:27.118: E/AndroidRuntime(812): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.accelerometer_sensor/com.example.accelerometer_sensor.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-27 20:39:27.118: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-27 20:39:27.118: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-27 20:39:27.118: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-27 20:39:27.118: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-27 20:39:27.118: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-27 20:39:27.118: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-27 20:39:27.118: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
04-27 20:39:27.118: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 20:39:27.118: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-27 20:39:27.118: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-27 20:39:27.118: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-27 20:39:27.118: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-27 20:39:27.118: E/AndroidRuntime(812): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-27 20:39:27.118: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at com.example.accelerometer_sensor.AccelerometerClass.AccelerometerInit(AccelerometerClass.java:20)
04-27 20:39:27.118: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at com.example.accelerometer_sensor.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
04-27 20:39:27.118: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-27 20:39:27.118: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-27 20:39:27.118: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-27 20:39:27.118: E/AndroidRuntime(812):  ... 11 more
04-27 20:39:30.119: I/Process(812): Sending signal. PID: 812 SIG: 9
```

here`s my main activity code:

```
 package com.example.accelerometer_sensor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        int [] AccVal = new int[3];
        AccelerometerClass acc = new AccelerometerClass();
        TextView acceleration;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
             acc = new AccelerometerClass();

              AccVal = acc.AccelerometerInit();

                acceleration = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.acceleration);

                acceleration.setText("X: "+AccVal[0]+
                        "Y: "+AccVal[1]+
                        "Z: "+AccVal[2]);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }


    }
```

and this is my AccelerometerClass Code ::

```
package com.example.accelerometer_sensor;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;

public class AccelerometerClass implements SensorEventListener 
{
    private static Context context;

    int [] Vals = new int[3];

    public int [] AccelerometerInit()
    {
        Sensor accelerometer;
        SensorManager sm;

        sm = (SensorManager)context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);       
        accelerometer=sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sm.registerListener(this, accelerometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL); 

        return Vals;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Vals[0]=(int)event.values[0];
        Vals[1]=(int)event.values[1];
        Vals[2]=(int)event.values[2];

    }

}
```

Thanks .

Comment: Post LogCat / Stack Trace.

Comment: i edit my question to put log cat , sorry for you but i`m new in android .

Answer (score 1):

Your context in `AccelerometerClass` is never set!

Possible solution:

```
public class AccelerometerClass implements SensorEventListener {

    int[] Vals = new int[3];

    public int[] AccelerometerInit(Context context) {
        SensorManager sm = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        Sensor accelerometer = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sm.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        return Vals;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

     @Override
     public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
         Vals[0] = (int) event.values[0];
         Vals[1] = (int) event.values[1];
         Vals[2] = (int) event.values[2];
    }
}
```

in your Activity use

```
AccelerometerClass ac = new AccelerometerClass();
ac.AccelerometerInit(this);
```

Comment: so , how i can set or how to get the readings anyway ??!! 

and thanks for reply.

Comment: I have added one possible solution

Comment: make sure you add unregister method on your own!

Comment: it does not solve my problem , Now , when i run it gives me error "System ui has stopped " and when I enter the app from menu it shows :
X:0 Y:0 Z:0 ??!!!

Comment: You are not doing anything with your values, you are just saving them?! That's why you see 0,0,0. I suggest you follow a tutorial like this one, nice and slow, one step after another. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-accelerometer-on-android--mobile-22125

Comment: i know this tutorial and it fulfill with errors for me , but i want to ask you question as code :: i call AccelerometerInit and send as parameter activity , then it goes to the class and executes it and saves the values in array and return the array , and i remove the values from array to another to show in the text view , why it does not show ?!?!  

execuse me again but i want to understand

Comment: You return the values that are equal to zero as they were never set and java sets inttialized int values to 0 on it's own. Tha values change in the onSensorchanged, look in your code. You are just saving them and not telling your activity that the values have changed. Here you should have an interface callback with which you tell the activity... Hey the values changed, display them, but if you just started Java coding, I suggest you move the code to MainActivity so you have access to it's variables and you don't need an interface.

Comment: i figured out now  that if i want to avoid 3 zeros problem i must edit the textview in onSensorchange() and that`s i was avoiding from the beginning , is it right ???!

Comment: Yes. You need to apply new values in onSensorChanged

Comment: but if i want to transfer these 3 vals from the class to the main activity , it can`t do with my current code , it will need to implement interface , right sir ?!! i`m sorry for disturbance

Comment: Yes, you need an interface. Google for a simple example.